# Using variable within reduce function

Tags: javascript, reduce

have a feeling I am missing something obvious here.  I was using a reduce function like so

```
const obj = this.data.reduce((ac,{Category, Count}) => (ac[Category] = Count,ac),{});
```

However, I now need Category and Count to be dynamic, using a variable.  As such, I have done

```
const cat = this.format.header[0];
const count = this.format.header[1];
const obj = this.data.reduce((ac,{cat, count}) => (ac[cat] = count,ac),{});
```

This does not seem to be using my variables though.  I have also tried using this within it, but this also does not work.

How can I use these variables within the reduce?

Thanks

Comment: do you have some data and the wanted result?

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're asking, but you can't do that with destructuring. You'll have to extract the properties explicitly.

Comment: What is `this` and `this.data`? Also, why don't you just use an arrow function with curly braces then define your variables inside of that?

Comment: sorry, this.data is an array.  This is a component in VueJS, I am passing stuff via props

Comment: You can't destructure those variables but you can pass them as a key to your object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use destructuring this way to approach what you want:

```
this.data.reduce((ac,{cat, count}) => (ac[cat] = count,ac),{});
```

That will try to access properties `cat` and `count` from the objects that belongs to the array, not the ones that holds your variables. However, you can do like this:

```
const cat = this.format.header[0];
const count = this.format.header[1];
const obj = this.data.reduce((ac, o) => (ac[o[cat]] = o[count], ac), {});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `cat` and   `count` variables inside the `reduce()` call back will refer to the properties `cat` and `count` on each object is array of objects `this.data`.

If you want to destrucutre the properties using variables. Then use following syntax

```
[propName]:newName
```

Here is your code.

```
const cat = this.format.header[0];
const count = this.format.header[1];
const obj = this.data.reduce((ac,{[cat]:cat, [count]:count}) => (ac[cat] = count,ac),{});
```